# awk - how to split the string found

Tags: string, awk, split

I use this script to find two string recursively in my directory path.
I need to split my string found using double occurences of':' as field separator.

- my string otput is something like this:
  *file_name:row_number:searched string*
- this is my script:
  find  -name '*.*' -print | xargs grep -Ersn '.*|.*' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | awk '{print substr($1,126,3)}'

thanks in advance

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Format your code and examples by prefixing with 4 spaces or use the editors `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or with `cut`

```
$ ... | cut -d: -f3
```

Answer (score -2):

Solved:

```
| awk -F":" '{ print $3}'
```